# What does this mean (<< and >>> in calculation)?

Tags: java, android

I found this integer variable declaration in a Java class:

**int i7 = ((0x1F & arrayOfByte[i][4]) << 9) + ((0xFF & arrayOfByte[i][5]) << 1) + (0x1 & (0xFF & arrayOfByte[i][6]) >>> 7);**

But are the arrows (>>> and <<) mean/doing?

Kind regards,
Bastiaan

**UPDATE:**
Sow they are bitshift operators, thanks!
Found this good explanation video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qa0zvcdHXI

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: >> bitshift right, << bitshift left, >>> looping bitshift right, <<< looping bitshift left (while looping means that the bit comes in on the other side of the 32 bit integer again)

Comment: Look who didn't do his research homework.

Comment: @TheWhiteLlama This is misinformation.  `>>>` is not a looping bit shift, and `<<<` is not legal Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throughout this post let's assume numbers are one hex digit, just for simplicity.

">>" is the bit shift operator.  For example:

```
8 >> 1 == 8 / 2 == 4;
```

Which in binary is equivalent to

```
b1000 >> 1 == b0100;
```

Adding the third ">" into the operator inserts a 0 into the now far left slot, instead of doing sign extension to determine it's value.

```
-1 >> 1 = b1111
-1 >>> 1 = b0111
```

This is more useful for things like bit masks, where forcing the new value to 0 is convenient.  And is only applicable to right shifting, there is no <<< operator.